# How can I use PKCS5 (RFC 1423) padding in C# manually for AES Decryption?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

My company has an old library that encrypted data for us. It is not able to be used in our new environment so I'm trying to write a decryption method for our old data.

The encrypted data had a padding of PKCS5, a.k.a. RFC 1423. In the process of using the .net AesCryptoServiceProvider class I have noticed there is no such padding scheme built into the enumerator. All my decrypted data is gibberish so far. We have no cryptography pro here, and I am learning on the fly. Any pointers to help are appreciated.

I'm currently implementing code as found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx).

This question is also posted on the cryptography site [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32610/how-can-i-use-pkcs5-rfc-1423-padding-in-c-manually-for-aes-decryption).  However they don't seem to address .net specifically so I also want to check with the experts here.

***EDIT***

The old encryption has the following settings which seem to cause an error in .net when done manually - specifically the IV and block size.

BlockSize: 16
CipherMode: cbc
CryptAlgorithm: aes
Hash: sha1
IV: byte[0]
KeyLength: 128
Salt: byte[0]
Key: byte[16]

So, the key and block size match as needed, but there is no IV set which throws an error in .net as well as the block size throws an error.

Comment: PKCS7 should work, because as [What is the difference between PKCS#5 padding and PKCS#7 padding](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/9043/13022) says, they are equivalent for AES (actually there is no such thing as PKCS#5 padding for AES). If using PKCS#7 padding doesn't solve your problem then there is something else going on.

Comment: Are you sure the content you are trying to decrypt has actually been encrypted using AES?

Comment: it is set to aes crypt algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [AesCryptoService padding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.symmetricalgorithm.padding(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation the default padding is PKCS#7. PKCS#7 padding is a superset of PKCS#5 padding.

See [PaddingMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.paddingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

PKCS#5 padding only was defined for an 8-byte block size, PKCS#7 padding extends the defined block sizes to 256-bytes. PKCS#5 was never a correct padding for AES which has a 16-byte block size but the name use was carried over from other historic encryption libraries.

See [PKCS#7 Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7).